# Determinant characterization of subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a linear vectorial subspace of the euclidean space and $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ a basis of $V$.

I'm asking an easy characterization of the elements of $V$ using determinants and the basis above. I think such a result already exists, but i can't find it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an example, suppose you have linearly independent vectors $u$ and $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, and you wish to determine whether a third vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is contained in the plane spanned by $u$ and $v$.  Form the $4\times 3$ matrix $A=[u\;v\;w]$.  Then $w$ is in the plane if and only if the rank of $A$ is 2, or equivalently the determinant of the product $A^t \, A$ vanishes. Similar considerations apply in higher dimensions.

Comment: Why is it equivalent to the determinant $A^tA$ equal zero?

Comment: The determinant of $A^t A$ is the square of the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the three vectors.  Look up "Gram matrix" in any linear algebra text, e.g. the class notes [here](http://u.math.biu.ac.il/~katzmik/egreglong.pdf).

Comment: Ok! Very thanks and nice criterion :)

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is a vector to be tested, we need the matrix formed by the coordinates of $[v_1,\ldots,v_k,v]$ to have rank less than $k+1$. You can impose this condition by asking all minors of size $k+1$ to have determinant zero.